# Dimension of open subset of affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, affine-varieties

> If $X$ is an irreducible affine variety and $U \subseteq X$ a non-empty and open (in $X$), then $\dim U = \dim X$.

The part $\dim U \le \dim X$ is clear, but I do not see how to prove the other part. All I can think of that is somehow similar is the common lemma:

> **Lemma:** For a general topological space $X$ holds that if $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ is an open cover of $X$, then $\dim X = \sup \{\dim U_i \mid i \in I \}$.

But I am not sure if we can apply that here. Could you please give me a hint?

REMARK: We defined the dimension via chains.

Comment: Please do some searching before asking next time - this question has been covered before on MSE.